# Adding server side code to angular-cli project conflicts with node typings

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

When adding a basic [express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) configuration (using TypeScript) to an Angular2 project that was initialized with angular-cli `ng new [project-name]`, I need to add the following typing to compile the express server using gulp:

> typings install --ambient --save node

This adds the following line to `typings/browser.d.ts` and `typings/main.d.ts`

```
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
and
/// <reference path="main/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
```

In the express `server.ts` file I can add a reference to `main` instead of `browser` to keep TypeScript happy

```
/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />
```

But when I leave the node typing reference in the `browser.d.ts` file, the `ng build` command will fail:

```
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  C:/Users/user123/Downloads/my-catalog-master/my-catalog-master/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-7VFCE2dg.tmp/0/src/typings.d.ts (3, 13): Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type 'NodeModule', but here has type '{ id: string; }'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:115:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.Plugin (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:10:31)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.CachingWriter [as constructor] (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:21:10)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:27:10)
    at Angular2App._getTsTree (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:280:18)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:101:23)
    at new Angular2App (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:42:23)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\angular-cli-build.js:6:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\tasks\build.js:15:19)
    at C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\commands\build.js:32:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\user123\Downloads\my-catalog-master\my-catalog-master\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

I could delete the line for now in `browser.d.ts` so it starts working again but that's not ideal when re-installing typings. I'm currently using `angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual error originates from the src/typings.d.ts file. Angular-cli creates this typings.d.ts file with the following content:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
declare var module: { id: string };
```

Removing this file solved the problem and the application is still working.

Comment: Can you please provide more info on how you were able to get the server side integrated with the angular cli? Do the "ng build" and "ng serve" also compile and run the server side code?

Comment: I don't compile server code with the angular-cli, I would also like to keep it that way. To prerpare a build I just use gulp. One task calls ng serve and another task starts the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you happen to have a link to a seed project that uses both angular cli as well as server code?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by changing `src/typings.d.ts`

From

`declare var module: { id: string };`

To

`declare var module: NodeModule;`

And making sure that I had typings for Node 4 via `typings install node-4 --ambient --save`.

Answer (score 0):

The error about .spec.ts file. When i update

> '@angular/testing';

code like

> '@angular/core/testing';

my error resolved;

```
import {
  describe,
  ddescribe,
  expect,
  iit,
  it
} from '@angular/testing';
import {Hero} from './hero';

describe('Hero', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(new Hero()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```